# Unrecognized token '8seged' in sqlite using c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

So when I try to create a table in sqlite, it just says that unrecognized token ('insert the name of the table here'). I don't know how to fix it, I asked everybody I know, and they don't either. Can some of you please help me? I've tried doing it with or without replacing, but to no avail.

```
        x.kapcsolodik();
        string sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 8seged; CREATE TABLE 8seged AS (SELECT datum, pontszam AS pont, helyezes as hely, ranglistaid FROM ranglista INNER JOIN elopont ON ranglista.id = elopont.ranglistaid INNER JOIN versenyzo ON versenyzo.id = elopont.versenyzoid INNER JOIN sakkozo ON sakkozo.id = versenyzo.sakkozoid WHERE szulnev = 'Kramnik, Vladimir')";
        sql.Replace("8seged", "'8seged'");
        x.parancs.CommandText = sql;
        x.parancs.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object names (such as tables) in SQLite can't start with digits. You'll have to a letter or an underscore (`_`) before the `8`.

Comment: Thank you! But with one error gone, there seems to be another. Now it says that there's a "'SQL logic error near "(": syntax error'", but I'm fairly sure that my SQL code should be working.

Comment: @PatrikKarakai you shouldn't surround the select with parenthesis - `create table mytable as select ...`